Assign Rigid Body and Collision to the same object
I'm trying to have an object fall (using real physics), and then "crush" another object. Using a few youtube videos, I've set up collision on the object, and soft body physics on the object it is hitting. The problem comes when I add the rigid body physics to the object to make it fall; it no longer collides with the soft body. Any suggestions?

You probably can"t mix all these physics and you need some tricks to get the desired result
